# Как зайти в базу данных в adminner

Tags: docker-compose

Я установил все через докер. Но момент что я не могу зайти в базу данных[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но не пойму что не так. Права досутупа вроде бы дал. Но зайти в базу не могу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3'

services:
  webserver:
    container_name: nginx_kfnp_yii2
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal
      PHP_IDE_CONFIG: serverName=localhost
    ports:
    - 80:80
    volumes:
    - ./:/var/www
    links:
    - db
    depends_on:
    - db

  db:
    container_name: mysql_kfnp_yii2
    image: percona:latest
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
    - 3306:3306
    expose:
      - 3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: yii2basic
      MYSQL_USER: mysqluser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mysqluser
```

И какой хост я должен использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Админнер нужно как [отдельный контейнер](https://hub.docker.com/_/adminer/) ставить.